# D3.js tipsy tooltips

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, protovis, d3.js, tipsy

Is D3.js able to supprt tipsy tooltip? Can someone show me an example if possible. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a forked version of tipsy created by Justin Donaldson that just got out.  Look for it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js/browse_thread/thread/637281220d7ac448).  I haven't tested it but it might be what you need.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a working example:

### [D3 tooltip using jQuery tipsy](http://bl.ocks.org/1373263)

[image]