# Showing tooltip on chart initiation

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way to show a tooltip for a pre-specified shape on chart initiation for a specific period of time?   The item could be random or hard coded.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to make the tooltip disappear.

Comment: Thanks,  how do I initially trigger the mouse over event on page load without actually doing a mouse-over?

Comment: Just run the code you run in the mouseover handler directly.

Comment: I'm using this line for tooltip.  plot.append("title").text(function (d) { return d.description; });   I could check if (description === "myitem") but how do I activate the tooltip? Just for that item on page load?

Comment: Just run this line where `d` is the datum bound to the item you want to show the tooltip for.

Comment: I'm still confused!  This will selectively enable a tooltip for 'myitem' but I want the tooltip to show even before mouse-over and then timeout as you mentioned earlier.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. You are running code in the mouseover handler to show the tooltip. Take that same code from the handler and run it at the start.

Comment: I'd like the cursor position on page load to be on the shape and trigger the mouse over but how do I set the x,y coordinates to make this happen?  Is there an easier way?  Here is my working fiddle example with tooltip:  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/L72Hq/

Comment: Found something similar to what I'm trying to do.  But the linked code is static.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136115/d3-js-tipsy-tooltips.   Is this straight forward to achieve?

Comment: I'm not getting any tooltips in your jsfiddle...

Comment: The tooltip should show the section on mouseover any rectangle.  It seems to work okay for me!